# WARNING:tensorflow:Entity

Tags: tensorflow

i tried to run the code from this repo https://github.com/zzh8829/yolov3-tf2/

then I ran in to this WARNING , it does find with the CPU with the WARNING below

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Entity <bound method BatchNormalization.call of <yolov3_tf2.batch_norm.BatchNormalization object at 0x00000297EAA0D828>> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: Bad argument number for Name: 3, expecting 4
```

after I installed tensorflow2.0rc
it does not work

my PC specifications:
CPU: i5-9400F

GPU: MSI RTX 2060

OS: Win 10

CUDA: 10

thank you guys

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, best I can find is that it is caused by latest version of gast (0.3.0). Need to install 0.2.2: `pip install -U gast==0.2.2`

[Source1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32448)
[Source2](https://eehoeskrap.tistory.com/363)